# Enqueue script to wordpress plugin not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, enqueue

I'm trying to add to my frontpage plugin a "Back to top Arrow" like

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_scroll_to_top.asp

I have put the JS code to a file and enqueued it.
Put the CSS code and enqueued it, an finaly put the HTML code for the button

I was able to enqueue the script file and CSS , since inspecting the page I can see the file and see the code inside.
But the button doesn't appear... Inspecting the page I get an error:

```
script.js?ver=5.3.2:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at scrollFunction (script.js?ver=5.3.2:9)
    at window.onscroll (script.js?ver=5.3.2:5)
```

If I put the JS code in the HTML page with the ... It work perfect.

It look like the JS code, when it's in a separate file, can't initialize the variable.

```
mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");
```

Because it's not ready.

How I can make to be sure that the page is loaded before the call of the `document.getElementById`?

I'm new to JS so please be simple :)

Comment: Post the PHP code for enqueuing

Comment: Set the `in_footer` parameter for `wp_enqueue_script` to `TRUE` (it's the last parameter)

Comment: what is the full script? it says there's errors on line 9.

Comment: The suggestion of disinfor was great, now work like a charm. :) Thx a lot